# how to design a webpage in asp.net design view which support multi resolution?

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, layout

I have created my webpage in asp.net in 1024*768 resolution, my problem was that when i change my monitor resolution then the controls in my webpage will be displayed in unmanaged manner .

How to arrange items in my webpage which support multiple resolution ...

Whatever the resolution of my monitor the controls in my webpage will display as it is as managed in 1024*768 reolution !

Answer (score 1):

This really has less to do with .NET and more to do with website layouts.  It sounds like you have a lot of inline HTML elements which wrap in a specific way at a specific resolution, but wrap differently at different resolutions.

Do you always want a defined width supported by 1024*768?  If that's the case (and often is in website design) then you can simply wrap your content in a `div` with a width set to the specific pixel width desired.

Furthermore, however, you'll want to get a good book on CSS and learn about that.  The Zen of CSS Design is a pretty good book on the subject, and similarly you can look through the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for inspiration and examples.  It's an extensive subject, but critical for good website design.

Comment: ya i want ..if i set my website controls and contents in 1024*768 resolution then  ... then all the contents will be permanently appear their as i is position ..whatevre the resolution is !

Comment: @user520818: The pros and cons of fixed width vs. fluid width website design have seen much debate for years.  There's actually a lot of interesting reading on the subject: http://www.google.com/search?q=website+design+static+width